# How can I insert pictures in (EPS/JPEG/PNG) format in a tex file?

Tags: graphics, luatex

I have a .tex file which goes something like this:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand*{\NewFont}[1]{%
  \expandafter\newfontfamily\csname#1\endcsname{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\SetFont}[1]{%
  \csname#1\endcsname
  \ignorespaces
}
\newdimen\FontSize
\newdimen\FontUnitLength
\setlength{\FontUnitLength}{.75bp}
\newcommand*{\SetSize}[1]{%
  \setlength{\FontSize}{#1\FontUnitLength}%
  \fontsize{\FontSize}{1.2\FontSize}\selectfont
  \ignorespaces
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\Put}{}
\def\Put(#1,#2)(#3,#4)#5{%
  %\put(#1,#2){\makebox(#3,#4)[lb]{\resizebox{#3\unitlength}{!}{#5}}}%
  \put(#1,#2){%
    \makebox(#3,#4)[lb]{%
      \resizebox{#3\unitlength}{#4\unitlength}{%
        \raisebox{\depth}{#5}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  %\put(#1,#2){\makebox(#3,#4)[lb]{#5}}%
}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}
\NewFont{Trebuchet_MS_Bold}
\NewFont{Verdana_Bold}
\NewFont{Georgia}
\NewFont{Arial}
\NewFont{Trebuchet_MS}
\NewFont{Verdana}
\NewFont{Verdana_Bold_Italic}
\NewFont{Trebuchet_MS_Italic}
\NewFont{Arial_Bold}
\NewFont{Times_New_Roman_Bold_Italic}
\NewFont{Georgia_Italic}
\NewFont{Times_New_Roman_Italic}
\NewFont{Verdana_Italic}
\NewFont{Times_New_Roman}
\NewFont{Courier_New}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(939,1287)
\SetFont{Courier_New}
\SetSize{48}
\Put(12,1249)(131,36){Swine}
\Put(159,1249)(55,38){flu}
\Put(230,1240)(181,47){tightens}
\Put(428,1249)(49,36){its}
\Put(492,1240)(84,45){grip}
\Put(592,1249)(99,27){over}
\Put(708,1249)(105,38){India}
\SetSize{19}
\Put(589,1192)(53,14){Swine}
\Put(649,1192)(23,14){flu}
\Put(681,1192)(29,14){has}
\Put(716,1188)(88,18){tightened}
\Put(813,1192)(19,14){its}
\Put(839,1188)(34,14){grip}
\Put(880,1192)(41,10){over}
\SetSize{17}
\Put(133,1156)(1,21){j}
\Put(590,1158)(312,18){India,withthedeathtollreaching}
\SetSize{20}
\Put(589,1131)(45,14){close}
\Put(641,1131)(18,13){to}
\Put(668,1131)(48,14){1000.}
\Put(725,1131)(47,14){Fresh}
```

and more......

I use the above latex file to finally create a PDF having words at particular placed XY Coordinates (known beforehand) where the put command is used. 
Now, apart from this, I also want to include the pictures (stored as seperate image files by the names 1.jpg, 2.jpg...) at particular X-Y Coordinates as I did with words.

What I did was, in the .tex file, I inserted this line (before the positioning of the word Swine): 
`\Put(415,1171){\includegraphics[width=515, height=243{/home/John/Desktop/1.jpg}}`

Here, (415,1171) are the coordinates and the path is the location of the image. 
When I try to convert the above tex file into a PDF, it shows an error (which without was working completely fine) and gives the following error and stops:

```
</home/John/Desktop/1.jpg, id=1, 516.93124pt x 243.91125pt>
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
```

Comment: There is a typo (missing `]` after `height=243`. I am not sure if you can pass dimensionless arguments to `width` and `height`. Try with `\includegraphics[width=515pt, height=243pt]{/home/John/Desktop/1.jpg}`

Comment: @John Package `textpos` can be used to position text and graphics at specific positions on a page.

Comment: @Aditya, it gives the following error: `Runaway argument?
4){\makebox (15,7)[lb]{\resizebox {15\unitlength }{7\unitlength }{\raisebox \ETC
.
! File ended while scanning use of \Put.
<inserted text> 
\par 
<*> abc
`. I think this error is coming because I am not adding the line at a proper place (that is, after word Swine). Do you think I should put it somewhere else?

Comment: @Nunkulla, how can I add it in this file? Can you give me an example by editing the above tex file?

Comment: Your `\Put` macro needs *two* couples of distances before text. Try `\Put(415,1171)(100,100){\includegraphics[width=515pt, height=243pt]{example-image}}`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit, that worked, but what if I have the top left (x1,y1) and bottom right (x2,y2) coordinates. should I just enter these coordinates as the two sets of coordinates in the put command?

Answer (score 1):

The `Textpos` package can be useful for this purpose.  The positioning of your elements would require a lot of interpretation so the following code is illustrative only. The textboxes in the example are shown relative to the margins, which are generated using the showframe option of the `geometry` package.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[lmargin=24mm,rmargin=24mm,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,showframe]{geometry} %Set margins and show them
\usepackage[absolute,showboxes]{textpos} % Positioning textblocks in absolute terms
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{textblock}{2}(24,25) % Place a * at the intersection at the top and left margins
    $*$ %Top left
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{40}(140,50) %Place an image in a box 40 mm wide 140 mm from the left edge and 50 mm from the top
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.20]{example-image}%From mwe package
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{20}(24,100) %Place a textblock on the left margin (24 mm), 100 mm from the top.
Swine \\
flu \\
tightens \\
its \\
grip \\
over \\
India
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{40}(90,120) %Place a textblock 90 mm from the left edge and 120 mm from the top
\raggedleft
Swine \\
flu \\
tightens \\
its \\
grip \\
over \\
India
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{2}(186,272) % Place a * at the intersection of the bottom and right margins
     $*$ %Bottom right
\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

[image]